# Sequelize, Mysql how to return deleted ids

Tags: mysql, node.js, graphql, sequelize.js, apollo-server

I have a GraphQL mutation that deletes items. I'm trying to retrieve the deleted ids. However null ids are returned but items are deleted from the database.

**Shema**

```
type Mutation{
  deletePropertyItems(id: [ID!]!): DeletePropertyItemsRes!
}

 type DeletePropertyItemsRes {
    success: Boolean!
    message: String!
    propertyItem:PropertyItem
  }

type PropertyItem {
    id: ID!
    title: String!
    description: String!
  }
```

**Mutation Resolver**

```
async deletePropertyItems(_, { id }, { models }) {
      try {
        const deletedRows = await models.PropertyItem.destroy({
          where: { id: id },
        });
        if (deletedRows) {
          return {
            success: true,
            message: "Property Item(s) Deleted Successfully!",
            propertyItem: deletedRows,
          };
        }
        return {
          success: false,
          message: "Operation not Successful",
        };
      } catch (error) {
        throw new Error(error.message);
      }
    },
```

**Apollo Studio Error**
[image]